# SharePoint with MVC 5 which best way to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

My question is what form **Hosting** should I use?

- **Provider-hosted**
- **Autohosted**
- **SharePoint-hosted**

Application will be on the server to be consumed by **internal users** and **external users**.

Our team consists of developers in **MVC** and have a person of **Sharepoint**, which standard to use MVC with SharePoint in this situation?

- We have to make the user log
- We need to read the list of Sharepoint
- It will be Workflow Sharepoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well SharePoint-Hosted is out of the question since you can only use client-side code. If you don't mind maintaining and setting up your own server environment, setup up a Provider-Hosted app. But if that's you're choice you'll have to read up on the authorization systems (can be a pain to setup).

It all depends on your application needs. But if you're still not sure read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268593.aspx), [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790706.aspx), [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/695161/Walkthrough-Creating-a-O-SharePoint-App-wi) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887.aspx).

Comment: I want some help with sample unfortunately if to look at all the sites you sent will not able to suggest a solution for that reason I am asking for help.